# C++ program crashes upon reading NULL reference

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, null, queue

This is a linked structure in C++. All of the variables and objects here should have defined addresses. However, the execution says otherwise.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
struct LineData {
    int ID;
    char name[33];
    LineData *next;
};

class Line {
    private:
        LineData *pointerHead;
        LineData *pointerToTail;
        int numObjects;
    public:

        Line();
        ~Line();

        void enterLine(int ID, char *data);
        void enterLine(LineData *lindat);
        LineData *exitLine();
        int count();
};

Line::Line() {
    pointerHead = NULL;
    pointerToTail = NULL;
    numObjects = 0;
    /*pointerHead = NULL;
    pointerToTail = NULL;*/
}

/** Puts an item into the line. **/
void Line::enterLine(int ID, char *data) {

    LineData *temp;
    cout << "Inner sanctums called.\n";
    temp = new LineData;
    temp->ID = ID;
    strcpy(temp->name, data);
    temp->next = NULL;
    cout << "Temp created.\n\n";
    //cout << "pointerHead is... ... " << pointerHead << "!\n"; Not going to work!
    /* Insert into the Line */
    if(pointerHead != 0) {  /* Insert as first in this Line/You shall not pass! Program will not let you pass! BOOM! Crash! */
        cout << "If tried.\n";
        pointerToTail->next = temp;
        pointerToTail = temp;
    }
    else /* Insert at Tail of the Line */
    {
        cout << "pointerHead == NULL. What are you going to do about it?\n";
        cout << temp->ID << "\n";
        pointerHead = temp;
        pointerToTail = temp;
        cout << "Inserted into Line!\n";
    }
}

/** ......
    ......
  ..........
  ..........
    ...... **/
```

Compiles properly.

```
int main() {
    Line *GeorgiaCyclone;
    Line *GiletteIce; // Shaved Ice.
    Line *WoodenMagic;
    Line *SteelCityNinja;
    Line *Egbe; // Hawk.

GeorgiaCyclone->enterLine(4, "Preston");
Egbe->enterLine(2, "Felix");


return 181;
}
```

The addresses for each line are set to NULL upon creation. Using `this` does not make a difference. How could this be happening? How may this crash be mitigated?

Comment: "A linked structure"?

Comment: _"All of the variables and objects here should have defined addresses."_ What objects? Literally none of your top-level pointers point to anything.

Answer (score 4):

```
Line *GeorgiaCyclone;
```

This creates a pointer to a `Line`, but doesn't create a `Line` for it to point at.  You need to assign it the address of a `Line`:

```
Line *GeorgiaCyclone = new Line
```

Better yet, you can avoid using pointers at all in `main()`:

```
Line GeorgiaCyclone;
```

The same goes for all of the other `Line*`s you've declared in `main()`.

Comment: Ah. I had thought that the address could just refer to `temp` once `temp` was created in the enqueuing function. I had misunderstood some instructions from someone else as well. It's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized non-static local variables have an *indeterminate* value, and in reality will be seemingly random and most seldom equal to a null pointer.

Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, or actually reading from *any* uninitialized variable, leads to *undefined behavior*.

The variables I'm talking about are of course the variables in your `main` function.

---

On an unrelated note, in C++ you should not use `NULL` for null-pointers; use either `nullptr` (preferred, but only in C++11 and higher capable compilers) or `0`. In C++ `NULL` is a macro which expands to just `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** initialize pointers otherwise the behavior is undefined...you must initialize a pointer to NULL if you want it to be NULL. However, dereferencing a NULL pointer is **still** undefined behavior, but at least you can check whether or not it's NULL. It's good to get into the habit of initializing everything.

```
Line *GeorgiaCyclone = NULL;    
if(GeorgiaCyclone!=NULL)GeorgiaCyclone->enterLine(4, "Preston");
else{//some code that alerts you to the fact that you have null pointers, perhaps a message box?
}
```

That way if you forget to assign a pointer your program will not crash.